# Pushing array into an array of array in TS

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, set

I am coming from Python, and am not entirely familiar with the 'proper' JS/TS way of doing things.

I am looping through the elements of a set, and I am pushing lists of some of the elements onto a 2D array.

```
let res: number[][];
for (let posElement of posSet) {
    if (negSet.has(-1*posElement)) {
        res.push([-1*posElement, 0, posElement]);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`. What am I doing wrong, where am I messing up the syntax?

Comment: You did not assign any value to `res`, and as a result its value is `undefined`. Something that will help you will be to use `const` everywhere you can - it'll help you catch errors easier

Comment: Alright, what are the necessary things I need to do in order to rectify that? It is an empty array that I want to pass things onto. As I said I am coming from Python, and this would be legal code there.

Comment: Assign a value to `res` so that it isn't `undefined`

Comment: It is empty, until I need it. What would I assign to it, if it is empty?

Comment: An empty array.

Comment: Given that it is a 2D array, is ```new Array()``` fine or is there specific syntax for 2D arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this initialize

```
let res: number[][]=[];
```